# WCF, WAS, IIS and ports

Tags: wcf, iis, port, was

**Hi,**

I have worked with WCF for a while now but there is somthing Im not clear on.

When hosting a WCF service in IIS the standard protocol will be http and the default port is 80. Its possible to change this portnr if needed.

Then its also possible to host a WCF service in IIS using the TCP protocol(WAS). The WCF service will however still publish its mex on port 80 on http prootocol but how do I see the port nr for the WCF TCP communication?

I Supose that I will have to open first the port nr for the mex(usually port 80) and then also the WAS(WCF TCP in IIS) port?

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see which port TCP will use by going into the website configuration in IIS and looking at the site bindings, then looking for (or adding, if necessary) the net.tcp binding. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28WS.10%29.aspx) is the documentation on how to configure bindings.

If I remember correctly, the default port is 808.

Comment: Yes I have also seen port 808 but when selecting the service in IIS7 there is no binding in the Action panel? And if 808 is used, should the client not set this in its config file?

Comment: The bindings option will pop up when you select the entire *website*, not the application or virtual directory. Bindings are always configured at the site level. As for the 808 not appearing on the config file: Where you'd normally see that is the URL used by the client, and if no port is specified in the URL, it will just use the default (808).